# Deleting objects within a list with shared_ptr

Tags: c++, list, shared-ptr, delete-operator, stdlist

My goal here is to delete a projectile whenever it hits something. I have a function in the projectile class that returns a boolean value of the state of the projectile (is to delete or not). The problem is that I don't know when and where I should delete it.

In my project, I'm creating a projectile and adding it in 2 different classes with a std::list. The first class (let's say it is in ProjectileGestion) contains all the projectiles and updates them each frame before sending them to a DrawGestion (The DrawGestion will put every sprite in order of y and draw them). The second class is a Quadtree that contains a list of all the objects within is perimeter (Each frame, it checks if each object in his list still fit in and will check for collisions). For the moment, I don't delete any projectile, since I don't know how. I thought of 2 options:

1. Only the ProjectileGestion can delete the projectile. Whenever it deletes an object, it deletes the object and changes the value of the pointer to NULL. In the other class Quadtree, when I cycle through the list with iterators, I check if each iterator is equal to NULL. If it is, the class will erase the iterator from the list and continue on.

   ```
   std::list<Object*>::iterator i = listOfObjects.begin();
   while(i != listOfObjects.end())
   {
   //Update()
   if((*i)->IsToDelete())
       {
          delete *i;
          *i = NULL;
          listOfObjects.erase(i++);
       }
   else
       {
          i++;
       }
   }
   ```

2: I use a std::shared_ptr when declaring the object.I do the same check up as I did in option 1, but I only erase the object from the list, I don't actually delete the object. That way, when every list will have erased the object from it, the object will be deleted. (Note that I never used smart pointers before).

So which way is more efficient and is less prone to cause a memory leak?

Comment: I would be tempted not to delete them, just to mark them as deleted. Then, when you need a new projectile, select one of those marked as deleted. That way you are not allocating/deallocating memory all the time. Also you may want to use a `std::vector` for your live projectile list as their cache-friendliness means they can out-perform `std::list` in many situations where you might think a `std::list` makes sense.

Comment: Well, it's my first project (I'm learning c++ at home), so I would like to keep it simple. My code is around std::list and "deletion" :/

Answer (score 0):

They should be about the same efficiency since std::unique_ptr will use template code that will add similar code to what you wrote.  However, using std::unique_ptr will be less error prone if you ever change that code or add other code that deals with the pointers.

More importantly, the unique_ptr code makes your intentions more explicit and makes the code easier to read and maintain.  You can tell by looking at the declaration that it's a list of exclusively owned objects and your erase becomes 1 line.

Comment: If I understand what you are saying, std::unique_ptr would be a plus to my option 1 ?

Comment: Yes - I misread your 2nd option as unique_ptr instead of shared_ptr.  I would make it std::list<std::unique_ptr<Object>> and then your 3 delete lines just turn into "listOfObjects.erase(i++)"

Comment: Thanks! I thought shared_ptr was the thing to go for